# Mongo collection not updating on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm learning how to use meteor and I'm having trouble syncing the clients collection with what the server has. I'm trying to make a counter that increments by one every time you click it by calling a method on the server. When I go to my application it always displays 1 but when I do .find() on my collection through the Mongo shell it has what the number should actually be. I have autopublish on so shouldn't this work automatically? Here is my code for both client and server:

```
/client/main.js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';
Counter= new Mongo.Collection('counter');
Template.counter.helpers({
  counter() {
    return Counter.find({});}
});

Template.counter.events({
  'click #a':function() {
      Meteor.call('add')

  },
});

/client/main.html
<head>
  <title>HypeCoins</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>HypeCoins</h1>

  {{> counter}}
</body>

<template name="counter">
  <button id='a'>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter.count}} times.</p>
</template>



/server/main.js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
Counter= new Mongo.Collection('counter');

Meteor.startup(() => {

});
Meteor.methods({
    'add':function(){
        Counter.update({},{$inc:{count:1}});


    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get your solution by using a modifier on your update. This will require you to create an ID so there is something to update. You can do so by:

client/main.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

Counter = new Mongo.Collection('counter');

Template.counter.helpers({
  counter() {
    return Counter.findOne();
  }
});

Template.counter.events({
  'click #a':function() {
    Meteor.call('add');
  },
});
```

server/main.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Counter = new Mongo.Collection('counter');

Meteor.methods({
    'add': function() {
      currentCount = Counter.findOne();

      if (!currentCount) {
        Counter.insert({ count: 1});
      }

      Counter.update({_id: currentCount._id }, { $inc: { count: 1 } });
    },
});
```

Refer to Meteor documentation: 
https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your collection schema. Take a look at that package it should be useful for you: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema